# IOS8 SplitVC + TabBarController + NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, adaptive-ui

I'm doing a universal App using size classes and I'm trying to use a SplitView with a TabBarController in the Master/Primary View. Before adding the splitView all worked fine, but now the App crashes (the reason depends on the hierarchy of the views).

So I tried the same storyboard starting from Apple SplitView template and add a TabBarController on its Master/primary view... same problem.

Hierarchy - Embedded master NavigationController in TabBarController:
SplitVC (Master) > TabBarController > NavigationController > TableView
SplitVC (Detail) > NavigationController > View

Added this code in AppDelegate.m (as seen here [stackoverflow questions ios8-tabbarcontroller...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580981/ios8-tabbarcontroller-inside-a-uisplitviewcontroller-master) to prevent DetailView being presented modally):

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController showDetailViewController:(UIViewController *)vc sender:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"UISplitViewController collapsed: %d", splitViewController.collapsed);

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if (splitViewController.collapsed) {
            UITabBarController *master = (UITabBarController *) splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
            UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)master.selectedViewController;
            UINavigationController *destinationNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)vc;

            // push detail view on the navigation controller
            [masterNavigationController pushViewController:[destinationNavigationController.viewControllers lastObject] animated:YES];

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

It works fine... unless you simulate in iPhone6 Plus, in that case, after starting in portrait and selecting a row, if you rotate in landscape I see the detail view as primary AND secondary view.

Without adding this code in portrait orientation with iPhones the detail view is presented modally and of course without navigation buttons.

***EDIT***

After different tries and with some external helps I've made some steps forward the solution.

**Short version** (See Long Version to know why you have to do this)

A correct solution to the problem is to subclass TabBarController and make it support some methods:

```
@implementation MyTabBarController

- (void)showViewController:(UIViewController *)vc sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class])
        [self.selectedViewController showViewController:vc sender:sender];
    else
        [super showViewController:vc sender:sender];
}

- (UIViewController*)separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
{
    return [self.selectedViewController separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:splitViewController];
}

- (void)collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController forSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
{
    [self.selectedViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:secondaryViewController forSplitViewController:splitViewController];
}
```

Now I have a problem with viewControllers stack: with the iPhone6Plus (the only one supporting both horizontal regular and compact) the App crash if, when in landscape, you change tab without selecting a row (so the detailView remain the one for the previous tab) and then rotate in portrait.

*I know that I have to implement separation and collapse methods managing the views stacks properly but I can't figure how. Can someone help on this?*

> **Long version** (SplitViewController behaviour)
>
> Normally a split view controller and a navigation controller work
>   together to ensure that a call to -showDetailViewController:sender:
>   from a view controller that is contained within the split view
>   controller results in the new detail view controller being pushed onto
>   the navigation stack (when in a horizontally compact environment).  To
>   do this, UISplitViewController overrides
>   -showDetailViewController:sender: and, if horizontally compact, calls its master view controller's -showViewController:sender: method. 
>   UINavigationController overrides -showViewController:sender: and
>   pushes the incoming view controller onto the navigation stack.
>
> UITabBarController however does not override
>   -showViewController:sender: and so it inherits the default implementation which presents the incoming view controller modally. 
>   To work around this I have to subclass UITabBarController and override
>   -showViewController:sender: to forward to the tab bar controller's selectedViewController if the selectedViewController is a navigation
>   controller.
>
> Furthermore, when a split view controller transitions from a compact
>   to horizontal size class to a regular horizontal size class, the split
>   view controller first sends a
>   -splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:
>   message to its delegate.  The delegate can implement this method and
>   handle the separation itself, returning the detail view controller. 
>   If the delegate does not implement this method, or if the
>   implementation returns nil, the split view controller sends a
>   -separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController: message to its primary view controller.  The primary view controller should implement
>   this method to handle the separation. The UINavigationController does
>   implement -separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController:. 
>   It's implementation pops the top view controller off the navigation
>   stack and returns it.  Because I am using a tab bar controller as the
>   primary view controller, I must implement
>   -separateSecondaryViewControllerForSplitViewController: and handle the separation by myself.
>
> Also I need to implement my own collapsing logic. When a split view
>   controller transitions from a regular to horizontal size class to a
>   compact horizontal size class, the split view controller first sends a
>   -splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:
>   message to its delegate.  The delegate can implement this method and
>   handle the collapse itself.  If the delegate does not implement this
>   method, the split view controller sends a
>   -collapseSecondaryViewController:forSplitViewController: message to its primary view controller.  The primary view controller should
>   implement this method to handle the separation.
>
> UINavigationController does implement
>   -collapseSecondaryViewController:forSplitViewController:.  It's implementation pushes the secondary view controller onto the
>   navigation stack.  Because I am using a tab bar controller as the
>   primary view controller, I must implement
>   -collapseSecondaryViewController:forSplitViewController: and handle the collapse by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found something that works, even if is not the standard behaviour:

```
- (void)collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController forSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
{
    [self.selectedViewController.navigationController collapseSecondaryViewController:secondaryViewController forSplitViewController:splitViewController];
}
```

That is equivalent to return always `YES` in the `splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:` delegate method. Like this you always discard the secondary controller.
Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet and told us your results. This snippet get from a website outside stackOverflow ([Craig Marvelley](http://marvelley.com/blog/2014/09/27/uisplitviewcontroller-collapsing-and-separating-in-ios-8/))

```
#pragma mark - Split view
// Update secondaryview with the right screen
- (UIViewController *)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController { 
int tryIt = 0;

if ((IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS) && (isLandscape)) {
    if ([primaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        for (UIViewController *controller in [(UINavigationController *)primaryViewController viewControllers]) {
            tryIt = tryIt + 1;
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && ([[(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[yourPosibleScreen01 class]] || [[(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController] isKindOfClass:[yourPosibleScreen02 class]]) ) {
                return controller;
            }
            // Sublevel where yo are to select the right screen. You must try with a number depends of how many internal hierarchy. But I believe you need number 2 but try it :) 
            if (tryIt > 2) {
                return controller;
            }
        }
    }
    // Update detail screen
    UIViewController *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourScreenToShow"];
    return toViewController;
}
return nil;
}


 - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {

     return NO;
}
#pragma mark - Split view
```

Comment: It doesn't work, same problem. Do you tried it? It work for you?

Comment: Hello @Zag, sorry but i forget a counter of levels. I don't know why, but sometimes (after change portrait to lands or viceversa) we have 3 screens and not just 2, I suppose is just for the order of internal action to shoe screen. The code above works for me.

Comment: Hi @Beto, AFAIK the SplitViewController hierarchy change depending on collapsed or separated mode. See  [this article](http://averagejake.com/post/104146203887/uisplitviewcontroller-adaptability-part-1). I'll try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I hope this help you and if you found something better please write it here.